# Material won't apply to mesh with UV map

Tags: materials, uv

I'm tryning to apply a Texture Image to an object, but it don't work. I unwrapped the object and created the image in the UV/Image Editor. If i try to assign any other simple materials with just color, it won't work either. In the material preview it's showing nicely. As you can see [image: here]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see the texture is because you are in solid view in the viewport shading.

Switch to material or rendered view.

[image]

**Bounding Box**.

Only shows rectangular boxes that outline an object’s size and shape.

**Wireframe**

Objects appear as a mesh of lines representing the edges of faces and surfaces.

**Solid**

The default drawing mode using solid colored surfaces and simple lighting.

**Textured**

Shows meshes with an image applied using the mesh’s active UV Map. For Cycles materials, the image is the last one selected in the Node Editor. For other render engines, the UV Map’s applied face texture will be shown.

**Material**

A fast approximation of the applied material.

**Rendered**

An accurate representation using the selected Render Engine and lit with the visible scene lights.

For more info please refer to the blender manual:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/shading.html

Comment: Thank you! I started to study blender 2 weeks ago, still got a lot to learn :D